# Opening a random file out of a selection with batch on startup

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm trying to use a batch file to open another random batch file (out of 6 possible) on startup. This gives me a different moving background using VLC. The file names are LB0.bat, LB1.bat ... LB5.bat. What I have now does not work.

```
set /a num=%random% %%6

FOR %%num DO start /min C:\LivingBackground\LB%%num.bat
```

Without the random function, it works fine. Ie, to open LB0.bat, i can just use;

```
start /min C:\LivingBackground\LB0.bat
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `FOR %%num DO`. Leave the rest of the line.

BUT

```
start /min "" C:\LivingBackground\LB%num%.bat
```

Note that batch variables are accessed by `%var%` ansd a syntax quirk makes the first `quoted string` in a `start` command the window title.

You're not using a string in your `start command, so the`""` is optional.

Comment: I get the error "Windows cannot find 'C:/\LivingBackground\LB%num.bat'. Make sure you typed the name correctly, and try again."

Comment: I've revised the advice - make sure `num` has exactly one `%` each end.

Comment: batch files `echo` the command they are about to execute line-by-line by default. Insert a line `@echo off` as the first line in the file to turn this characteristic off.